# where is Payment Method part of Magento invoice coming from

Tags: magento, templates, invoice

I modified this once before, but I have forgotten where this part of magento invoice comes from.!

[image]

\app\design\frontend\default\MYTHEME\somewhere?

Comment: I don't have an admin at hand, but as far as I remember that is the name of the payment service set in admin > system > configuration > sales > payment methods > YOUR PAYMENT > Title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email template for a new Invoice is located at app/locale/en_US/template/email/invoice_new.html around line 64. I believe the Payment Method content is generated in the following file: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml.